# Dynamic Creating PostgreSQL tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL, In this case, I passing data object frontend to backend and I want to create a table regarding those objects by choosing the datatype also,
below is the image of the object (those objects depend on our submitting files, also those fields can be changed , also length can be changed);
[image]

also, the table name must be the **TemplateData.templateName** in the object. the fields must be **TemplateData.columns**
In the image, you can see **rowData** Object, I passed that to identify the Datatype of each column, and how should I check the datatype and how to create a table for this kind of situation.

Thank you.

Comment: Please review [ask]. Following that as a template greatly enhances your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In particular here **do not post images**, convert them to formatted test. Also, what have you tried.

Comment: Thank you I will go through and I will ask a better way any asking questions